# jQuery run animation with defaults prevented on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run an animation slideDown with some delays and a slideDown on document load, but i want it to prevent the defaults of the slideDown action as the element has position:fixed;

I believe that i am doing it wrong as it will not load at all, could you please assist;

i have it here on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLBaD/1/

and here is the code;

```
    $(function(){

    $('.initial').hide();

    var initial = $(".initial");
    jQuery(function(){
        preventDefault();
        if (initial.is( ":hidden" )) {
            initial.delay(3000).slideDown(1000).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);    
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$(function(){
    var initial = $(".initial");        
    initial.hide().delay(3000).slideDown(1000).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLBaD/5/

Answer (score 2):

in the jQuery you have a lot of unnecessary code, just do:

```
  $(".initial").delay(3000).slideDown(1000).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);
```

And hide the element with css (faster) so it doesnt have to load javascript to hide.

**see working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fLBaD/3/